# how to get the unique items in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the html file like below:

```
<div id="ultreecurri" style="float:left;">
<ul>

<li id="li1" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">International</li>
<li id="li10" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Science</li>
<li id="li332" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Physics</li>
<li id="li2" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Africa</li>
<li id="li3" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Asia</li>
<li id="li5" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Caribbean</li>
<li id="li8" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">North America</li>
<li id="li9" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">South America</li>
<li id="li1" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">International</li>
<li id="li10" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;"> Science</li>
<li id="li332" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Physics</li>
<li id="li2" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Africa</li>
<li id="li3" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Asia</li>
<li id="li5" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Caribbean</li>
<li id="li8" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">North America</li>
<li id="li9" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">South America</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

how can i get the unique text of li items according to their liids.

Comment: This HTML is malformed. IDs cannot be duplicated, or jQuery/js will behave weirdly.

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = [],
    txt;
$( '#ultreecurri li' ).each( function() {
    // Cache the text to avoid retrieving twice the same property
    txt = $( this ).text();

    // If the text isn't in the array, add it
    if ( $.inArray( txt, items ) === -1 ) {
        items.push( txt );
    }
} );
console.log( items );​ // Array of unique values
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/Vz7ev/1/

You'll see that "Science" is not the same as " Science". You may want to use `$.trim` (which strips off leading and ending spaces) if that bothers you. Just change the following:

```
// Replace this:
txt = $( this ).text();
// With this:
txt = $.trim( $( this ).text() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is invalid because you're not allowed to give the same id to more than one element.

Having said that, if your question is how to get a list of unique values from the content of the li elements:

```
var workingObj = {},
    uniqueVals = [];

$("#ultreecurri li").each(function() {
   var val = $(this).html();
   if (!(val in workingObj)){
      workingObj[val] = true;
      uniqueVals.push(val);
   }
});

// uniqueVals array now contains one of each unique value.
```

As an aside, setting the same inline style (`text-align: left;`) makes for ugly markup, and makes ongoing maintenance more trouble than it needs to be. I'd remove those and add that to your existing `popupul` class. Or if you can't change that class for some reason add this to your stylesheet:

```
#ultreecurri li { text-align: left; }
```

Comment: Surely you don't need both vars here. If you are filtering workingObj and only adding to it if the var is not in there, then it will only contain one of each unique value as well, no?

Comment: Overengineering? :-) Simply using `$.inArray` should be enough, shouldn't it? :-)

Comment: @LiamBailey - `workingObj` is there to avoid using `.indexOf()` on the array on every iteration of `.each()`. As far as I know looking up a property in an object is more efficient, and also this will work in older browsers that don't support `.indexOf()` on arrays (IE < 9).

Comment: ... and jQuery provides the `inArray` method, a cross-browser `indexOf` equivalent.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - For some reason I never think to use jQuery's `$.inArray()`. (But one day I'll get around to testing whether the object property lookup is more efficient.)

Comment: Testing is done! http://jsperf.com/prop-lookup-vs-indexof it's faster to use `inArray` :p and don't worry, this method doesn't always pop up in my mind either

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - Thanks for doing that test. I notice the `$.inArray()` version performed better even though it repeated `$(this).text()`, though in FF it was 5,383ops/sec versus 5,373ops/sec - not a huge difference. This is a very small array though, less than a dozen values - perhaps the property lookup would be quicker if we were talking about using `inArray()` on an array with hundreds of values?

Comment: I edited to remove the double lookup, it doesn't change much (I guess jQuery caches that). Maybe it'd be slower with more items, I don't really know... I don't see why it'd be though, since it's faster with not many items (because you'd have to look at an object with hundreds of properties too).

Answer (score 0):

The markup contains so many duplicated `ID` so, it is not a valid Markup. Instead I suggest you to remove the duplicate element, thus having a unique element on an array.

Here is a snippet for this purpose.

```
var list = {};
$('li').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (list[id])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        list[id] = $(this);
});
```